# How to fill missing values with values from matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

What steps I need to do to fill missing values like this? Center of matrix can be in any position.

```
 ____________
|* *  *  *  *|
|* *  *  *  *|
|* *  1  2  3| 4
|* *  5  6  7| 8
|* *  9 10 11|12
 ------------
     13 14 15 16

 ____________
|1 1  1  2  3|
|1 1  1  2  3|
|1 1  1  2  3| 4
|5 5  5  6  7| 8
|9 9  9 10 11|12
 ------------
     13 14 15 16
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do @AlexandrMakarov. Can you add more details?

Comment: I'm trying to make my own image processing library. I convert a bitmap image into two-dimensional array. For example, I want to make a gaussian blur method and I have a matrix 5x5 of values for gaussian blur. So I need to multiply color values of image by gaussian value then summirize them and set is as value of pixel that in center of matrix. But at the edges I dont have any value of color so I found that I can just fill them with near values. But I don't know how filling algoritm should work.

Comment: Have you code that you can share, I might get a better understanding from that.

Comment: Find the central non * value, fill everything up to its x/y with that value, then fill columnar upwards the column values from the row it's on, then fill rowar leftwards from the column it's in the values from the rows of the column it's in, it's 3 lots of a nested loop pair